# error spawning sdf models in gazebo under ROS groovy

Tags: gazebo, groovy, gazebo-1.2, sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

When trying to spawn a sdf model in Gazebo 1.2, I get the following errors:

*Error [SystemPaths.cc:281] Unknown URI prefix[models/static_sphere.sdf]*

*Error [ModelDatabase.cc:219] Unable to download model[models/static_sphere.sdf]*

*Error [ModelDatabase.cc:391] Invalid model manifest file[/manifest.xml]*

*Error [World.cc:1201] Unable to read sdf file.*

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 with ROS groovy, Gazebo 1.2.5.

I set up the variables with: *source /path/gazebo-1.2/setup.sh*

The paths in the **manifest.xml** file look like this:

*gazebo gazebo_media_path="${prefix}"*

*gazebo plugin_path="${prefix}/lib"*

Do I have to set up other path variables in the ROS package?

Thanks,
Andrei

**UPDATE:**

I have a ros package in **~/ros_package/** with the **/models** and **/world** folders in it.

There I use a [world plugin](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B-_Uvr2wQxS3M0ZGYXo2RUNHM1k) to spawn models from my package (this used to work in Gazebo 1.0.2 with Fuerte, and it doesn't with 1.2.5 under Groovy). Here is my [manifest.xml](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B-_Uvr2wQxS3RlNwam85S3ozWVk) file from the package where the paths should be loaded.

As a workaround I copied all my models into **~/.gazebo/models** and spawned them directly from the **world file**. But this is not very portable I would prefer setting up the paths in a way that I can use them from my package (I tried all the combination with the **gazebo paths**, and still had these errors).

This question is somehow related or may be duplicate of [this](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/433/gzfactory-spawning-not-working-in-gazebo-12/?answer=450#post-id-450) one.

Cheers,
Andrei

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/415/error-spawning-sdf-models-in-gazebo-under-ros-groovy/) by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 2108 on 2012-12-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2012-12-12**:
I'm unclear on what you're trying to do, can you update your post with the command your running, the version of gazebo, the exact output of gazebo, and the directory structure of your model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo looks the `GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH` to find models.

In your case:

`export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=~/ros_package/models:$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH`

Gazebo looks in the `GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH` to find world files.

In your case:

`export GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH=~/ros_package/worlds:$GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH`

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2012-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0